# How to Compare Only Date from DateTime stamp in php?

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a column with name `DDateTime` and it's type is `DateTime`.

I want to compare only date from `DDateTime` with input date.

Example: '14-05-2018 08:00:00' = '14-05-2018'

How can I compare only date from `DateTime` variable?

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM ride 
        WHERE RideFrom = '$RideFrom' 
        and RideTo = '$RideTo' 
        and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DDateTime, 103) = '14-05-2018';";
```

I tried this query but it did not work

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Do you want to change your SQL statement to only check the date? Or do you want to do that within your PHP code?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can us the MySQL `DATE()` function for this and make it really easy

```
AND DATE(DDateTime) = '14-05-2018'
```

> Although I have to mention that your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 0):

Here is two methods.
Choose the one you like.

```
$str ='14-05-2018 08:00:00';

echo substr($str, 0, 10). "\n";
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($str));
```

Substr will always take the first ten characters, whatever they are.
Date will try to parse and make it unixtime then convert to datestring.